# Is it possible to add a multiple titles in UITableView with only 1 section

Tags: ios, swift

Because everything is coded already for 1 section.

If I add more sections now I'm getting errors like:

`fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

and the app crashes.

Comment: Do you mean how to add multiple labels in one section?

Comment: Multiple header titles. example: header one 2 rows header two 2 rows

Comment: Just redo everything to work with sections. Now your data is probably stored in a single array/dict. Just make it a nested collection (array in array). It will cost you a little bit of time now, but much much easier to use the existing header system than implementing your own method.

Comment: The problem is i bought the app but he is giving bad support and says is too much work. I can do only some reskinning and few other things, so i thought maybe there is a simple way.

Comment: There is a simple way: Learn Swift/UIKit for reals, don't take shortcuts, make al the awesome apps.

Answer (score 2):

Here we go, Use the below code :-

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //Below wil set title of headers
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        var headerTitle : String?
        if section == 0
        {
            headerTitle = "Section1"
        }
        if section == 1
        {
            headerTitle = "Section2"
        }
        return headerTitle
    }

    //Below method wil return number of sections
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
    {
        return 2
    }

    //Below method wil return number of rows in sections
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        var sectionIndex : NSInteger=0
        if section == 0
        {
            sectionIndex=2
        }
        else if section == 1
        {
            sectionIndex=2
        }
        return sectionIndex
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reUsecellIdentifier") as?  UITableViewCell
        if cell == nil
        {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: "reUsecellIdentifier")
        }
       if indexPath.row == 0{
        cell!.textLabel!.text = "First Row"
        }
        else{
            cell!.textLabel!.text = "Second Row"
        }
        return cell!
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    }
}
```

OutPut:-

[image]